# Susy gem install breaking SASS

Tags: css, ruby, sass, gruntjs, susy-compass

Hi I've just installed SASS and Compass in to my project folder using the command terminal, I've configured my Grunt file so that every time I save my SASS it updates my CSS and live reloads the page. I've just tried to install Susy, the install goes fine using `gem install susy` but now when I save a change in my SASS files this message appears on the terminal:

[image]

It says done without errors but the CSS isn't updating and the live reloads isn;t working either. I've at least managed to get it back to it's previous state using

```
`gem uninstall susy`

`gem uninstall compass gem uninstall sass`

`gem install sass --version "3.2.10"`

`gem install compass --version "0.12.2"`
```

my config.rb file is set up like this

```
`require 'susy'
css_dir = '_/css'
sass_dir = '_/components/sass'
javascripts_dir = '_/js'
output_style = :compressed`
```

I'm new to this any help would be appreciated - should I install different versions of SASS/Compass/Susy?

**Update**

Having looked at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22555984/compass-and-susy-require-a-different-version-of-sass?rq=1) it may be that susy and compass require different version of SASS and are currently conflicting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

installing pre-release versions of compass fixed this `gem install compass --pre`